# R: ggplot2 - stacking and dodging in bar graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet

Use a toy dataset to create a simple bar graph with facets using `ggplot2` package:

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(reshape2) # to convert to long format 

databas<-read.csv(data=
                    "continent,apples,bananas
                  North America,30,20
                  South America,15,34.5
                  Europe,15,19
                  Africa,5,35")

databaslong<-melt(databas) 

# plotting as colored bars 
ggplot(databaslong, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=variable))+
  geom_col()+
  facet_grid(.~continent)
```

and get the following:

[image: simple bar plot with facets]

How to put apples over bananas (or vice versa)? Why does the directive `position="stack"` (or `position="dodge"`) have no effect here in `geom_col()` or elsewhere? (the facets always come with bars dodged)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified `x=variable` in your aesthetic mapping, so each value in variable (ie. apples & bananas) gets its own position along the x-axis, and there's nothing to stack.

If you want apples & bananas to be stacked for each continent, you can specify `x=continent` instead:

```
ggplot(databaslong, 
       aes(x = continent, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]